# How to get the bypass a folder name which is not constant to copy files from one folder to another using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I need to copy all files from certain folders which are updated regularly. I thought of automating this using PowerShell.

I want to copy the files from Source folder to Destination folder which are provided in the below code.

Now, I have used get-date to match the date folder (2020-04-15) also to bypass "randomfolder", I tried using "**.txt" in the path and it worked.

Please find the latest code below:

```
$destination = "C:\Users\Mitu\Desktop\Test\Destination\"

$source = "C:\Users\Mitu\Desktop\Test\Source\"

$datefolders = Get-ChildItem $source

$TodayString = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

foreach($folder in $datefolders)
{
    $foldername = $folder.ToString()
    if ($foldername -eq $TodayString)
    {
        Write-Host $foldername
        $path1 = $source + $foldername + "\*\*.txt"
        Copy-Item -Path $path1 -Destination $destination -Force
        Write-Host $path1
        break
    }
}
```

Please help me with the necessary improvements that can be made in the above code.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: Your if condition does not work. You need to use `-eq` inestead of =. Second your variable path will not be a proper path. You need to use `$file.FullName`. And you should use a filter at your `get-childitem` to find all csv's and then loop trough them and then copy thoese files.

Comment: _lots of gotchas_ [*grin*] ... [1] you define `$Source` twice. [2] you do not define `$Destination`. [3] your `IF` is doing an assignment, not a comparison. [4] your `IF` is trying to compare a FILE object with a DATE string. that won't work - you need to compare comparable things. [5] your `$Path1` will give you an invalid path since it adds the `\*\` to the end of a FILE name AND it fails to add the needed path delimiter after `$Source`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: I want to only copy the files under today's date folder. How can I compare the folder name with today's date?

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal - how do you identify the files-to-be-copied? will there be other "random" dirs under the `$Source` dir, or only the one? ///// you haven't provided enuf info to do the job, yet. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: There will be only one random name folder inside the date folder.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: This can be used to convert the date datatype to string write? `$date = Get-Date
$TodayString = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal - you can get a date string from a datetime object that way. i would likely do it in one step - `(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: Done. Have edited the question as well. Please help me to match the randomname folder?